# How to stop firebase error in flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

my app isn't building again, don't know what I did wrong. The error message  is listed below

```
C:\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:9: error: package androidx.annotation does not exist
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                          ^
C:\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:10: error: package androidx.annotation does not exist
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                          ^
C:\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:638: error: cannot find symbol
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" In this case I'd expect that to be/include your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the latest version of some of the Google plugins where they migrated to AndroidX. I've made a [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1120) with a fix but it likely won't be reviewed before Monday.

A workaround meanwhile is to downgrade to a working version in your pubspec. E.g. I had `firebase_storage: ^1.1.0`, and after looking at the [changelog](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_storage/CHANGELOG.md) to identify a previous version, I changed that line to `firebase_storage: 1.0.4`.

Answer (score 6):

### **Solution**

Add: `implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1'` to the **build.gradle** of **firebase_auth library**. I used Android Studio to see the flutter android app structure.

---

#### **From Android Studio**

[image]

#### **Sample Code:**

**build.graddle(firebase_auth library):**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    dependencies {
        api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
        implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1'
    }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml(dependencies)**

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart: ^0.20.0
  firebase_core: ^0.3.0
  firebase_analytics: ^2.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.0+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But please also add that we need to Migrate to Android X the /android folder of the firebase_auth plugin using Android Studio

Comment: I didn't have to migrate the android folder, just adding that line to the libarary's build.gradle file solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to migrate your project to AndroidX. You can refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) to migrate your project. And also see change logs for firebase_auth [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth#-changelog-tab-).

Comment: I was able to get my project to work without downgrading. I did migrate my project to AndroidX and I bumped the version of GoogleSignIn to 3.3.0.

Answer (score 2):

I've added this in `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

It helped me